# Magento2 prevent reindex after adding product programmatically

Tags: magento2, products, indexing, reindex

I have made a module that adds a grouped product to the catalog. After adding some products I always have to reindex to see the changes. If I add a product via the Admin, this does not seem to be necessary.

Is there a way to only update the indexes for the added product instead of having to update all product indexes?

**I have pasted the code I use to add a product below:**

```
$product = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setSku($iceProduct['sku']) // Set your sku here
    ->setName($iceProduct['title']); // Name of Product
    ->setDescription($iceProduct['descr_long']); // Name of Product
 //enz...
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 6):

1. inject \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory to the __construct method
2. instantiate it as class variable ($this->_indexerFactory right now)
3. run the following code after saving product:

> `foreach ([ /* feel free to delete indexers which not require reindexing */
>               'catalog_category_product',
>               'catalog_product_category',
>               'catalog_product_price',
>               'catalog_product_attribute',
>               'cataloginventory_stock',
>               'catalogrule_rule',
>               'catalogrule_product',
>               'catalogsearch_fulltext',
>
>           ] as $indexerId) {
>               $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create()
>                   ->load($indexerId)
>                   ->reindexRow($product->getId());
>                   //->reindexAll();  // <= use it to reindex whole everithing
>           }`

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful solution to reindex for a particular product